# QGIS creates a custom CRS when using a defined CRS

Tags: coordinate-system

I am trying to use the world_azimuthal_equidistant CRS in QGIS 3.4.2. When I try to re-project a layer from WGS 84 (the default) to the World_azimuthal_equidistant CRS, it automatically generates a custom CRS instead of the world_azimuthal_equidistant CRS. Is there a reason a custom CRS is automatically being generated?

Answer (score 2):

"world_azimuthal_equidistant" looks like an Esri-defined coordinate reference system.  QGIS recognizes the [EPSG-defined](http://www.epsg-registry.org) CRS.

There's a new version (6) of the PROJ library which does recognize Esri-defined CRS but I don't know which version of QGIS has it or will have it.

If there's a well-known ID (WKID) and the value is ≤32767, than the definition has been defined in the EPSG geodetic parameter registry. Values over that are defined by another authority. The WKID for "World_Azimuthal_Equidistant" is Esri:54032.

Disclosure: I work for Esri and I'm a member of the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.